# Unable to deploy Growthbook service (A/B Testing) together with Nginx sidecar container for handling SSL/TLS encryption into Amazon ECS

Tags: docker, nginx, amazon-ecs

I want to deploy Growthbook (A/B Testing tool) container along with Nginx reverse proxy for handling SSL/TLS encryption(i.e SSL Termination) into AWS ECS. I was trying to deploy using Docker compose file(i.e Docker ECS context). The problem is, it is creating all the necessary resources like Network Load Balances, Target Groups, ECS task definitions etc. And Abruptly fails creating ECS service and tries to delete all the resources it created when I ran `docker compose --project-name growthbook up`. Reason it says is "Nginx sidecar container exited".

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3"
x-aws-vpc: "vpc-*************"
services:
  growthbook:
    image: "growthbook/growthbook:latest"
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 3100:3100
    environment:
      - MONGODB_URI=<mongo_db_connection_string>
      - JWT_SECRET=<jwt_secret>
    volumes:
      - uploads:/usr/local/src/app/packages/back-end/uploads
  nginx-tls-sidecar:
    image: <nginx_sidecar_image>
    ports:
      - 443:443
    links:
      - growthbook
volumes:
  uploads:
```

And Here is `Dockerfile` used to build nginx sidecar image:

```
FROM nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ssl.key /etc/nginx/ssl.key
COPY ssl.crt /etc/nginx/ssl.crt
```

In the above `Dockerfile`, SSL keys and certificates are self-signed generated using `openssl` and are in order.

And Here is my `nginx.conf` file:

```
# nginx Configuration File
# https://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration

# Run as a less privileged user for security reasons.
user nginx;

worker_processes auto;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

http {

    #Redirect to https, using 307 instead of 301 to preserve post data

    server {
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name localhost;

        # Protect against the BEAST attack by not using SSLv3 at all. If you need to support older browsers (IE6) you may need to add
        # SSLv3 to the list of protocols below.
        ssl_protocols              TLSv1.2;

        # Ciphers set to best allow protection from Beast, while providing forwarding secrecy, as defined by Mozilla - https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Nginx
        ssl_ciphers                ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:AES128:AES256:RC4-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

        # Optimize TLS/SSL by caching session parameters for 10 minutes. This cuts down on the number of expensive TLS/SSL handshakes.
        # The handshake is the most CPU-intensive operation, and by default it is re-negotiated on every new/parallel connection.
        # By enabling a cache (of type "shared between all Nginx workers"), we tell the client to re-use the already negotiated state.
        # Further optimization can be achieved by raising keepalive_timeout, but that shouldn't be done unless you serve primarily HTTPS.
        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m; # a 1mb cache can hold about 4000 sessions, so we can hold 40000 sessions
        ssl_session_timeout  24h;


        # Use a higher keepalive timeout to reduce the need for repeated handshakes
        keepalive_timeout 300; # up from 75 secs default

        # remember the certificate for a year and automatically connect to HTTPS
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains';

        ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl.key;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; # TODO: replace port if app listens on port other than 80

            proxy_set_header Connection "";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3100; # TODO: replace port if app listens on port other than 80

            proxy_set_header Connection "";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, Growthbook exposes its service on `http://localhost:3000` and `http://localhost:3100`. And Nginx sidecar container only listens on port `443`. I need to be able to proxy to both endpoints which are exposed by Growthbook from Nginx port `443`.

Help is much appreciated, if you guys find any mistakes in my configuration :)

By default, Growthbook service does not provide TLS encryption. So I used Nginx as sidecar handling SSL Termination. As a end result, I need to be able to run Growthbook service using TLS encryption hosted on AWS ECS.

Comment: Since the Nginx container is exiting, have you checked CloudWatch logs for any log output from Nginx before it exits? There may be an error message in there that would help pinpoint the problem.

Comment: That's the tricky part, I removes the cloudwatch logs associated with nginx as well. So how to figure out :(

Comment: Try tailing the log as soon as the deployment starts? Or run the deployment with an IAM user that doesn't have permission to delete logs?